# Более того(,) если ты ешь гранат, то у тебя время просыпания вдвойне сокращается!

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Более того(,) если ты ешь гранат, то у тебя время просыпания вдвойне сокращается!

Мне просто не нравится, что перестановка невозможна.

> Более того, **то** у тебя время просыпания вдвойне сокращается, если ты ешь гранат!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Более того, если ты ешь гранат, то у тебя время просыпания вдвойне сокращается!* — *более того* — вводный оборот, который требует после себя запятую. Перед высказыванием был какой-то текст, который соединяется с оборотом *более того* через точку.

*Более того если ты ешь гранат, то у тебя время просыпания вдвойне сокращается!* — ’более того’ = ’выше какой-либо установленной нормы’.

Второй вариант, без запятой, можно переделать, чтобы было понятней:

*Если ты ешь гранат более того, то у тебя время просыпания вдвойне сокращается!* — ’Если ты ешь гранат больше какой-либо нормы’.